# Bootstrapper "Unable to read registry value"

Tags: registry, bootstrapper

In boostrapper package.xml I am trying to read MSSQL entry from the regsitry like:

```
<InstallChecks>
    <RegistryCheck Property="CheckSQLInstalled" Key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server" Value="SsrpActiveServer" />
</InstallChecks>
```

After I run the result setup.exe I get in the log:

*"Reading value 'SsrpActiveServer' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'CheckSQLInstalled'"*

I run it as Administrator. UAC is off also...
The path in registry is correct. I can even retrieve it with BAT file like:
    Reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server" /v SsrpActiveServer

The problem happens on more than one machine. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setup.exe will run as a 32bit process, so on a 64 bit PC it will be reading

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server

SsrpActiveServer value does not exist at that location.